# Issue Xcode change char "@" to "%40"

Tags: json, xcode, web-services, afnetworking

I've use the AFNetworking in my app.

When I'll use the AFN with field EMAIL appear this error:

```
Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x1096634a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://mywebservice/vlemail?email=me%40domain.com, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x109558d10> { URL: http://mywebservice/vlemail?email=me%40domain.com } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 967;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 28 Apr 2014 19:01:43 GMT";
    Server = "nginx admin";
} }, NSUnderlyingError=0x1096756e0 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"}
```

It's weird, because the field EMAIL is: 
NSLog(@" txtEmail.: %@",_txtEmail.text) = [2908:60b]  txtEmail.: me@domain

But in the params of the AFN is changed to: me%40domain

Somebody knows why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the @ sign is encoded as %40, similarly to how a space is encoded as %20.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding